# Как спозиционировать блочный div относительно строчного img?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне правильно спозиционировать `div` относительно изображения?

Ведь `img` это строчный элемент, а `div` блочный, задаю img `position: relative`, а div `position: absolute`, но это не работает, потому что див должен быть внутри, но это не возможно же сделать. Псевдоэлементом думал, но тоже не вариант, ведь у меня целый `div`.

Comment: Я думаю стоит скинуть пример своего кода. Так будет проще решить задачу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
*{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}



.container{
margin: 0 auto;
width: 500px;
border: 1px solid gray;
position: relative;
}

img{
width: 50%;
display: block;

}

.one{
border: 4px solid black;
width: 20%;
height: 40%;
position: absolute;
left: 17%;
top: 10%;
}
```

```html
    <div class="container">
        <div class = "one"></div>
        <img src="https://lifetimemix.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/1800x1200_cat_relaxing_on_patio_other.jpg" alt=""> 
    </div>
```

Если я правильно понял -_-

Comment: вроде так, классный котик ^-^

Comment: @ПростаMiha (＾◡＾)

Comment: Большое спасибо!) Это и нужно было!